# mysql syntax ERROR 1064 while creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, create-table

I am creating a trigger for my tables:-
bank
Bank(pin, deposit, withdraw, balance, accno*, sno)
and
balance
Balance(accno*,balance)

I want to update the value of balance in my balance table after insertion in the bank table.
 **I am using a MySQL server** *(wamp64 mysql8.0.18)*

```
mysql> create trigger update_account
    -> after insert on bank
    -> begin
    -> update balance as a
    -> set a.balance=(case
    -> when new.withdraw=1 then a.balance-new.withdraw
    -> else a.balance+new.withdraw
    -> end)
    -> where a.accno = new.accno;
```

but the above code gives me the following error:-
**ERROR 1064 (42000)**: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update balance a 
set a.balance = (case
when new.withdraw=1 then a.balance - new.' at line 3

Comment: Have you reassigned the DELIMITER? And FOR EACH ROW is lost...

Comment: Does `bank.withdraw` is pseudo-boolean (0 or 1 values only)?

Comment: @Akina No, I didn't reassign the delimiter. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Akina   bank.withdraw contains the amount withdrawn.

Comment: *withdraw contains the amount withdrawn* If it is an `amount` then why you compare it with `1`?

Comment: create trigger update_account
        ->     after insert
        ->     on bank
        ->     for each row
        -> begin
        ->     update balance as a
        ->     set a.balance= a.balance + new.withdraw + new.deposit
        -> where a.accno=new.accno
        -> end;
how to add a delimiter to this code.

Comment: @Akina I added the delimiter and now it's working.Thank you so much.

Comment: Do not forget to reassign it back after trigger creation. :)

Comment: If you are not certain that a balance record exists at the point when you post to bank it would be a good idea to test such a case and create one if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE my_procedure$$
create trigger update_account
after insert
on bank
for each row
begin
update balance as a
set a.balance= a.balance + new.withdraw + new.deposit
where a.accno=new.accno;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My code is now working 
thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You should create trigger query same my code:

```
create trigger update_account
    after insert
    on bank
    for each row
begin
    update balance as a
    set a.balance=(IF(new.withdraw = 1, a.balance - new.withdraw, a.balance + new.withdraw))
    where a.accno = new.accno;
END;
```

And if you have only two cases, you should `IF`, not need `Case when`

Comment: In single-statement trigger BEGIN-END block is excess.

Comment: I still get an error. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
update balance as a
set a.balance=(if(new.withdraw=1, a.balance-a.withdraw' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger contains **ONE** statement. So it does NOT need in BEGIN-END block and DELIMITER re-assigning:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_account
AFTER INSERT
ON bank
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE balance
SET balance = balance + new.withdraw + new.deposit
where accno=new.accno;
```

Comment: if any of the columns in  balance + new.withdraw + new.deposit is null then the result will be null - a null test might be useful.

Comment: @P.Salmon Of course. But if so I think that OP will ask another question or solve this problem by herself.